# how to associate a newly created EC2 security group with an instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

How do I add an EC2 instance to a newly created security group? The security group was created with

```
client = session.client("ec2")
group_id = client.create_security_group(
    DryRun=False,
    GroupName=group_name,
    VpcId=vpc_id,
    Description=description
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to modify the attributes of the instance:

```
modify_attribute(attribute, value, dry_run=False)
```

`modify_attribute` changes an attribute of this instance. Use the attribute **groupSet** - *Set of Security Groups or IDs*

```
i.modify_attribute('groupSet','sg-xxxx5678')
```

See [boto.ec2.instance](http://boto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.instance.Instance.modify_attribute)

Comment: This mostly worked for me, except I found the documentation was incorrect and the parameter keys were: `Attribute`, `Value`, `DryRun`. I also found that the value, despite being called a set, is actually a string.